# 2 dimension geometric layout of objects

Tags: c++, algorithm

so I have this class:

```
class Piece{
  int width;
  int height;
}
```

my problem is that I need to make a container type class that somehow can save the layout of multiple and different size "Piece" objects (note that Piece can only represent rectangles).

Example:

```
________
| t     |
| t  jj |
| t  jj |
_________
```

My goal with this is to be able to "fill" a empty rectangle with multiple "Piece" objects but with the ability to know if the "Piece" can fit in.

I'm developing this in C++. I started with the most logic solution I think that was to use a "matrix" of vectors (vector< vector< Piece * > > mat) but that doesn't work because as I said "Piece" objects can have different sizes.

I hope you can give some hints on how to get a solution for this or if it exists some lib or open-sorce project links.

Thank you.

**EDIT**

I forgot this:I know beforehand the dimensions of the container and the insertion (after validation) is sequential (Piece after Piece) with no predefined orientation.

Comment: You likely want a tree of `Pieces`

Comment: You might want to store the position in your `Piece` class.

Comment: Look into AABB tree. You need some sort of two-dimensional data structure, like an R-Tree or AABB tree.

Comment: I'll check the tree option later. Storing the position inside Piece class is not a solution because it'll make much harder to know if there is space available (I think). Thank you all.

Comment: Of course, depending on how many pieces there are, and how often you add/remove pieces, there may be no need at all to store them in a fancy data structure. A simple vector or list of pieces may be sufficient, with a full traversal done for collision detection.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that but my intention is to balance memory usage with cpu usage. So, if I choose to do a collision detection every time I need to update de container I'll have more cpu usage and a low memory usage.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Piece p[width][height] and use memset to make all zeros or use a std::vector if you don't know the size of the grid beforehand. Then you can check(while adding a new Piece at some position (x, y)) if on any of its subsquares there is some other Piece already.

Edit: You can use a matrix char mem[sqrt(width)][sqrt(height)]; and a one vector of Pieces. Then using the matrix if there will be a probable collision and if not, just add the Piece. Else you iterate through all the existing ones and check for a collision.

If you want to make the procedure faster( this one is reasonable only with small grids ), then you will need to use more "advanced" data structures. What I suggest you is to learn about 2D BIT(or fenwick) trees(there are a lot of resources on google). You can also use 2D segment trees. Then when adding a new Piece at position (x, y) check the sum of all squares in it(e.g from (x, y) to (x + width, y + height)). If that sum is zero then the new Piece won't collide with previous ones and you then update the grid as you add 1 to all squares in your Piece(I mean to the corresponding values in the 2D segment tree). Else if the sum is greater than zero it means that there will be some overlap and you must then discard the new Piece.

Comment: I'll check your answer with more detail later. 

I'll add some info that I missed in the question (check edit).

Comment: After reading more carefully your answer, I came to this: 
first option - not the most reasonable one. You are suggesting having a position ([i][y]) for each unit which isn't the best option, because I'll have pieces like 2000*1500 and it would make it harder to check if a "Piece" would fit in a certain position.

Comment: If you want to balance between memory usage and cpu usage, you can use sqrt decomposition. See my edit for more info.

Comment: Can you please explain better your "edit option"? Thank you.

Comment: Lets suppose that you want to check if there will be a collision when adding piece on coordinates (x, y) with size (w, h).  Let k = sqrt(maxw) and n = sqrt(maxh). Now let a = x / k and b = (x+w)/k, c = y / n, d = (y+h)/n. In the array check if there is a piece at any of the indices from (a, c) to (b, d) - or in other words if there is 1 in that subarray.If there isn't, you can add the piece. If there is, you must bruteforce check if the new piece collides with some previous one, because the array check might give some false positives

Comment: I'll write down your explanation and try with some values to see if it's worth of a try. A big thank you!